# Getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error suddenly when it was working before

Tags: java, socketexception

We are using java to connect to a webservice. Everything was working fine just a few days ago but suddenly now we are getting com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset errors.

Nothing was changed on our code to connect to webservice. I have checked with the other party and nothing has been changed on their end recently.

I am unable to understand, how all of a sudden we are getting the following errors.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
*com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:133)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
    at $Proxy125.submitNonCompliant(Unknown Source)
    at servlets.submit.submitting(Unknown Source)
    at servlets.submit.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:121)
    ... 30 more*
```

Comment: Any changes in your Network? Proxy, firewall ...?

Comment: I've checked firewall settings are same as before when it was working

Comment: try to use telnet to see if you get an answer of the remote system.

Comment: Jens, if you don't mind, would you be able to tell me what do I need to get telnet to work? Sorry I haven't used it before

Comment: try `telnet <hostname> <port>` to see if you get an response or the same error message.

Comment: You've changed something to do with SSL, or the peer has: see the last part of the stack trace. @Jens As this is SSL, `telnet` is not going to work at all.

Comment: I tried connecting to host from telnet (putty) and I just get a connection time out error. Is there anything else I can try

Comment: Thanks for your input EJP. As far as I know, nothing has been changed on our server. Same code, credentials, endpoint everything is working on a different server. On this server it was fine just a few days ago when it suddenly started throwing these exceptions. Everything is working fine for a different endpoint on this server. Is there anything else you can suggest?